# Can A Sincere Convert practice Hebrew Calligraphy?

Tags: art

I want to create Hebrew art. As a sincere convert am I allowed to do so? For example, I wish to draw a Magen (Hebrew letters not the Star) to protect myself. I also read certain restrictions on sculpting, are there similar rules for painters?

Note* I have drawn a Star of David with the word חסד on the inside of it so sometimes my art would have both.

Comment: Why would'nt you be allowed to do so? (creating Hebrew art)

Comment: "H' protects all those that love Him" - Ps. 145.  A "Magen David" has, in many places, become a Jewish symbol, but there's some controversy (earlier pagan usage; Rothschilds).  A letter Hei is a common "artform" - presumably it's a reminder of Hashem as in "I've placed Hashem before me always" - Ps. 16.  Also I can personally recommend the name of the Tzaddik, נ נח נחמ נחמן as always appropriate to say orally and to be present written everywhere, per the words of Sabba Y' Odesser.

Comment: נ נח נחמ נחמן מאומן - I neglected to include Meuman per Saba z"l

Comment: Hooo! Comment from a friend: ב"ה ספר המידות ערך בנים ב:ח הא הנעשה מכסף מסגל לפריה ורביה.
ועיין בספר המידות עוד כמה סגולות. Translation, Sefer haMidot: Section "Banim/children, Part Two #8" - A Hei made of silver is a Segulah for "be fruitful and multiply." See also Likutei Moharan 53 related to this.  ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of all the positions of "dominating authority" (*srarah*) for which it can be problematic for a convert to take, I've never seen scribe/artist/calligrapher on the list. So the convert status should make no difference.

But backing up a step ... please have a conversation with a good rabbi about what kind of images and forms Judaism allows one in general to make. (Your status as a convert doesn't particularly matter vis-a-vis this conversation.) Sculpting vs. drawing is an interesting question -- please ask it separately.

I'm quite iffy on this notion of "draw a star and it will protect you" (remember, God is in charge).

I'd also advise you to check in with some Jewish artists about what sort of work they do.

Best wishes applying your talents in a spiritual way!

Comment: Apologies Shalom, as I meant to say not draw a literal star of David but the Hebrew letters מגן

Comment: I wanted to add 9 yud's and three alephs